# wildcard subdomain is not working with static subdomain on live server

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-403, wildcard-subdomain

I deployed my project on live server by creating subdomain `app.example.net` on cpanel. And put my project in `app.example.net` folder.
In my project I have two route groups like below

Routes.php

```php
<?php

Route::group(['domain' => 'app.example.net'], function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return redirect('http://'.session('subdomain').'.example.net/home');
        }       
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('homepage');   
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::get('/setupCompany', 'CompanyController@setupCompanyForm')->name('setupCompanyForm');
    Route::post('/setupCompany', 'CompanyController@setupCompany')->name('setupCompany');
    Route::get('/register/verify', 'CompanyController@verfiy')->name('registerVerify');

});

Route::group(['domain'=> '{subdomain}.example.net', 'middleware' => 'checkSubdomain'],function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('companyLogin');
    Route::post('/', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@login')->name('companyLogin');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'customAuth'],function(){         
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::post('/inviteClient', 'HomeController@inviteClient'); //ajax req
        Route::get('/profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
        Route::put('profile/password', ['as' => 'profile.password', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@password']);

        Route::get('/getClients', 'HomeController@clients'); //ajax req

    });
});
```

here is my .htaccess file in project's public folder

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

when I go to `app.example.net` it works but when I go to wildcard subdomain e.g `abc.example.net` it gives `404` error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

how to resolve this error so that wildcard subdomain also works.

Comment: Check the `.htaccess` file

Comment: @smartrahat i updated my question check .htacces file

Comment: Check the server's PHP version. It may not compatible with your current Laravel version.

Comment: @smartrahat it is compatible, my static routes are working but wildcard routes are not working